# Capture variable-length group that is zero-padded in a fixed-length string

Tags: .net, regex, string-parsing

I use regex to validate strings in a set and extract several pieces of data from each valid string.  I want to improve the extraction to, in effect, trim the zero padding from capture group 1.

Valid string sequence is 20 chars:

- literal `00100`
- 6 alpha-num chars

  - 1-6 meaningful chars (chars I want in one capture group)
  - left zero-padded up to 6 chars
- 9 digits

(S1) is a valid string: `00100000C13540040124`
(R1) is my current regex: `^00100(\w{6})(\d{4})(\d)(\d{4})$`

(R1) returns four capture groups from (S1):

- g1: `000C13`
- g2: `5400`
- g3: `4`
- g4: `0124`

I need to modify (R1) to:

- return g1: `C13` (left zeroes are trimmed)
- maintain all other capture groups
- maintain validation requirements

I *cannot* trim g1 using code outside of the regex.  I *can* add and re-number capture groups if needed.

(R2) is my attempt to exclude zero-padding: `^001000{0,5}([^0]{1,6})(\d{4})(\d)(\d{4})$`

(R2) returns the desired four capture groups from (S1):

- g1: `C13`
- g2: `5400`
- g3: `4`
- g4: `0124`

(S2) is an *invalid* string: `0010000000P3436040077`
(S3) is an *invalid* string: `0010000P3436040077000`

(R2) fails to reject (S2), which is 21 chars, but *happens* to return correct capture group data:

- g1: `P3`
- g2: `4360`
- g3: `4`
- g4: `0077`

(R2) fails to reject (S3), which is 21 chars, and *also* returns incorrect capture group data:

- g1: `P3436`
- g2: `0400`
- g3: `7`
- g4: `7000`

I have two other ideas, but I don't know if or how I could make them work with the .NET regex parser:

- count zero padding and dynamically size g1's size accordingly (ex. when 4 zeroes, g1 will effectively be `(\w{2})`)
- keep (R2)'s variable-length clauses (`0{0,5}([^0]{1,6})`) and validate 20 char length in an independent clause

I'm open to other ideas as long as they meet my requirements.  Thanks for considering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `[^\W0]` to match a word char except for 0 because `[^0]` would match any char except a 0 which is a broader match. Then match 0-5 word chars using `\w{0,5}` to make it a total of 1-6 chars.

You could use this with `R2` that you tried, and prepend a positive lookahead to assert that the string contains 20 word characters.

```
^(?=\w{20}$)001000{0,5}([^\W0]\w{0,5})(\d{4})(\d)(\d{4})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\w{20}$)` Positive lookahead, assert a string length of 20 word chars
- `001000{0,5}` Match 00100 followed by 0-5 times a zero
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\W0]\w{0,5}` Match any word char except 0 followed by 0-5 word chars
- `)` Close group
- `(\d{4})(\d)(\d{4})` Capture group 2, 3 and 4 matching the digits at the end
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d%5cw%7b20%7d%5cr%3f%24%29001000%7b0%2c5%7d%28%5b%5e%5cW0%5d%5cw%7b0%2c5%7d%29%28%5cd%7b4%7d%29%28%5cd%29%28%5cd%7b4%7d%29%5cr%3f%24&i=00100000C13540040124%0d%0a%0d%0a0010000000P3436040077%0d%0a0010000P3436040077000&o=m)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the positive look-ahead worked perfectly. Your answer also corrected a second error in (R2) that I hadn't noticed: ([^0]{1,6}) would fail if g1 had a zero to the right of non-zero chars.  That's Friday afternoon code for you! :)